# Cannot connect to ITunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to update my existing app in appStoreConnect.
But when I try to access MyApp after I login with my account in appStoreConnect, it keep saying

**"We can't process your request. Go back to where you were and try again"**

When I try to access to MyApp Session. 
I already tried clearing cache and using different browser. But still not working.

Comment: Can you please explain in details.

Comment: Current problem is I cant access MyApp Session in AppStoreConnect. 
It keeps showing above error. @iOSTeam

Comment: have you added any extensions in your browser?

Comment: Noting, I already tried with both Safari and Chrome, even with different Mac. 
It keeps showing same error.

Comment: please refer this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99687

Comment: Didn't help me bro. 
Is there any other way to update my app apart from appStoreConnect.

Comment: go to http://developer.apple.com
then logged into your account and you find a new agreement , so  just accepted the agreement